# MySQL 1005 Error - What's wrong with the query?

Tags: mysql

I'm unable to see the issue with this CREATE TABLE sentences. I've double checked but can't find the error.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `agentes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agentes` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `codAgente` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `clave` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `apellido1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `apellido2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `usuarioDA` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `passDA` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
COLLATE = latin1_spanish_ci;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cola`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colas` (
  `idCola` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `cliente` INT NOT NULL ,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCola`) ,
  INDEX `fk_colas_clientes1` (`cliente` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_colas_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente` )
    REFERENCES `clientes` (`idCliente` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `relColaExt`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relColaExt` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `codAgente` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `cola` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `prioridad` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_relColaExt_agentes1` (`codAgente` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_relColaExt_colas1` (`cola` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_relColaExt_agentes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codAgente` )
    REFERENCES `agentes` (`codAgente` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_relColaExt_colas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cola` )
    REFERENCES `colas` (`nombre` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

It throws #1005 - Can't create table './centralita/relColaExt.frm' (errno: 150) creating the relColaExt table.

It's a Foreign Key issue but I'm not able to see what's wrong. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: can you post the clientes table? A common reason for this error is that the referenced column and the foreign key column data types differ

Comment: It throws the error on the relColaExt table which doesn't reference 'clientes' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html#c10771) on MySQL manual page on Foreign keys, it may be due to different encoding of the VARCHAR columns. In table `agentes` you defined a collation but in `relColaExt` you did not.

Try using the same collation on every table (by defining it or by letting the default kick in).

Comment: I've tried to delete collations but it also doesn't work. Throw the same error.

Comment: Try to create an index in `colas.nombre` and `agentes.codAgente` the same way `relColaExt.cola` and `relColaExt.codAgente` indexes' are defined, then.